# ListBox SystemColor for Inactive Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I have changed the following SystemColors already:

```
<!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                 Color="Transparent" />
<!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent" />
```

I'm not sure what to call it, but which SystemColor is responsible for what I'm calling the: "InactiveSelectedItem"? It changes to this color every time I lose focus on the SelectedItem.

Would be nice if someone could help me. I used blend already to check but I can not find. The color is `#F0F0F0.`

Example:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` (.NET 4.5)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Could not find it in Blend.